# HTTP 1.0 505 HTTP Version Not Supported

Tags: c#, http

I am trying to write into the stream and read the response from the server. Below is the code I am trying to write.

```
sw.WriteLine("POST /{0} HTTP/1.0\nContent-Length: {1}\r\n{2}\r\n", name, location.Length, location);
```

Ideally, it should respond with "HTTP/1.0 200 OK" but it is responding with pretty much what I sent but with a message stating "505 HTTP Version Not Supported"

Any ideas?

Comment: The message should be clear enough... whatever code you're using to open/connect the StreamWriter is using an unsupported HTTP version. Maybe if you showed a concise version of all relevant code.

Comment: Use version 1.1. Pretty much any server nowadays supports 1.1 primarily due to the performance benefits.